# How to sync a generic type between a parent and child component in flow?

Tags: flowtype

I have two components that work in tandem (parent child relationship) and they must share generic types. So when you instantiate the parent with one specific type, all the child components must be restricted to take only that type on their generic.

So for example, I want this to fail:

```js
<Parent onChange={console.log} value={5}>
    <Child value="5"/>
</Parent>
```

However, I haven't been able to make that work (AKA fail). I look at flow docs about [abstract component](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-abstractcomponent) but I don't think that can help in this scenario.
This is a small reproduction of what I have tried so far:

```js
//@flow
import type { ChildrenArray, Element } from 'react'
import React, { Children, type Node } from 'react'

type ParentProps<T> = {
  onChange: (value: T) => void,
  value: T,
  children: ChildrenArray<Element<typeof Child>>,
}

export function Parent<T>({
  children,
  value,
  onChange,
}: ParentProps<T>) {
  const childComponents = Children.map(children, (child) => 
        React.cloneElement(child, {
          onSet: () => {
            onChange(child.props.value)
          },
        })
    )
    return <div>{childComponents}</div>
}

type ChildProps<T> = {
  children?: Node,
  value: T,
  onSet?: () => void,
}

const Child = <T>({children, onSet}: ChildProps<T>) => {
  return <button onClick={onSet}>{children}</button>
}

<Parent onChange={console.log} value={5}><Child value="5"/></Parent>
```

Here is the [link to the TryFlow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTACDMBsHsHcCgCWBbADtATgFwARYJ6oCmOA3jgMIAWikAJhkQHYCCGGAhvgDQ4CikIsma4AvjnAZoyHAHJGHAMZZZSNJlwAlIkqy9y1Wg2a8CxHADlodEuMnS5C5avhmSABQ6MmWd1NQAzgA8ACoAfDgAvGTwODjQTNQcTADmRABcOAAUAG4ckACuGTghAJRRETnQiHTcsTh5hcUhdXGKNPTemYadzGyc+EECQiJBbtDglB10YWF1ovDwRAAe6NgSBUzKiAk4nt5YoWFZpPXtRt6tDflFVwlJqUTzmfsiftCBR+WnbQkBuOd6BRpOgmCIAlEphdmAA6ZAcVBZQHGJi8JHTcqRCL1OK4nDaXQwxQwMHDYQ+dFGfQ4vG4hIAZSIWEyWUxER+tM59yoyTSlPoMNQ-gCMMaRVKNM5oiuUoleLluMYWAKGCYOCCdEQOTCpGRwPUYJ8AVEQWAmu18AWrkIJB6dHen3CkI5yO8AH5MlYbFcxc07kxGVgPdk2Q1qrVLYtFH9cHbIUcTq6TPEA0zRN1pg7guFQxylSq1UEAEYFLBYXb3SCIRQAa0ipAZaZ1SaYJuAJbLCTCkfgQVePhTDzS9ejTAC0EEMJgKXEvvrAFZRGEgnG5wAiedr4DL4D9rBhIA) reproduction

Comment: I'd expect something like this to work `children: ChildrenArray<Element<ComponentType<ChildProps<T>>>>` but flow fails to parse this

Comment: Yes, that indeed express what I want to build. So maybe this needs to be an issue on the flow issue tracker?

Comment: we will see! The only way to know is to open it.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8582